# Check-in Android project having dependencies to SVN

Tags: android, svn

I have added **google play services lib** as a dependent library to my Android project as shown.

[image]

I need to checkin the code to SVN .
 Do i need to checkin the google play services project as well? 
Or Is there any way i can package the google play services project along with my Android project?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Google Play Services` should be used as an `Android Library Project`. So you shouldn't pack it in any way. Usually I don't like committing external libraries in the `versioning control system`, and I prefer letting everybody clone and import the library projects locally. You could though add the library project into a different folder, and commit it to your source control if you find it more convenient.

Another alternative would be to use `Maven` for dependency management.